# Access gstreamer output on GPU

Tags: python, video, gstreamer

I am working with Gstreamer and Python to decode a video using HW acceleration on Nvidia GPU:

```
rtspsrc ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink
```

The following pipeline can be access using OpenCV which will return a numpy array. However, since I need to process the resulting frame on the GPU, I was wondering if there is any component that I can use to replace `appsink` that would allow me to access the frame directly on the GPU using any cuda library (e.g. `cupy`, `pycuda`).

Answer (score 0):

`appsink` should not force the memory to be downloaded to the host. But `videoconvert` definitely will download the texture to host memory though.

Use something like this:

```
rtspsrc ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! glcolorconvert ! appsink
```

You should get buffers with caps `video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory)` in the `appsink` then.

If you don't want to download the texture you probably cannot use the regular buffer map functions on these buffers. But I guess you can go forward with the GstGL library functions:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gl/index.html?gi-language=c

Comment: Thank you for the pipeline above. Do you know if there is any way to access the `appsink` on the `GLMemory` using Python?

Comment: I don't hvae it at hand, but the whole Gstreamer C API should have equivalent Python bindings. In any of the docs you can switch the langiuage to Python too.

Comment: Is there a guide on how to install the OpenGL plugins for GStreamer? Install them with apt but I guess I need to export some path because my Gstreamer can't find the plugins.